# How can I track user credentials coming from my program

Tags: sql-server

For my program I am using MS SQL and .NET to send a username and password for a SQL user.

Somewhere in my code that I cannot find it is sending the wrong username and password.

Is there any trace tool I can use on the client side to see what is being passed? I don't have access to the server and i cannot reproduce locally.

Comment: You could use a packet sniffer like wire shark: http://www.solarwinds.com/products/freetools/response-time-viewer-for-wireshark.aspx?gclid=CjwKEAiAmuCnBRCLj4D7nMWqp1USJABcT4dfPx8SADCRGMG96hwzYjImkPx0xVOd9mVfODK0GsjgwxoC3Nzw_wcB&program=18902&CMP=KNC-TAD-GGL-NETMAN_FREE_TOOLS-X-T5FT-NA&ef_id=U34@2gAAAT8vL7Ym:20150305191504:s

Comment: Ouch!!!! Instead of finding the rogue code you need to modify your code so that ALL of your credentials are in your config file. That is why they exist. Sending in login credentials from the code is a very poor design choice.

Comment: It is supposed to be that way... for some reason no one can figure out where the rogue code is coming from.